# android: how to create multiply views screen?

Tags: android

I want to create an activity, which shows a question with 4 answers, and at the bottom of the screen i want to place a timer.

I have already found timer example, and i created a question with the answers. the problem that they are 2 different projects and activities, and i am looking for the best way to implement it. i think i can't show 2 activities on one screen, but i can show 2 views or shell i use the ViewGroup, or maybe to copy-paste one of the activities code to another ( its the easiest way but probably the most ugliest way to implement it).
please tell me what is the best way, that i will study and not to waste time to study all the ways and only then to choose one of them.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.

You are correct in that you cannot display two activities at once. You must instead look into how layouts work in Android by reading some [tutorials on the Android developer guide.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)

For your layout, I would recommend using a LinearLayout with four TextView objects inside it containing the questions (and perhaps your EditText objects below them) as well as your timer. Make sure they are all inside a ScrollView so the software keyboard doesn't force it all to be squeezed up. This is how I would approach it, but I encourage you to read about how layouts work and use the XML resources.

The [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) is an excellent way to get started with views and text entry, as well as using SQLite databases.